# Single adb shell command to find the current apk location and version

Tags: android, adb

**Using the following 3 commands, Can we have single adb shell command to know the current apk file location and version of the apk.**

1. we can use following command to find the all packages and locations of the apks

   adb shell pm list packages -f
2. we can use following command to know the current package name.

   adb shell dumpsys window | grep -i mCurrentFocus
3. we can use following command to know apk version

   adb shell dumpsys package my.package | grep versionName

This will be use full for every one to quickly check the current apk details immediately.

**Example:** If i open com.src.test application from device. i want to know where this apk installed (/system/app/) and version of apk (1.0101) using single adb shell command.

Comment: Whats the question?

Comment: Updated the question could you please check now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this maybe?

```
package=$(dumpsys window windows | grep mCurrentFocus | cut -d'/' -f1 | rev | cut -d' ' -f1 | rev) && dumpsys package $package | grep -E "versionName|codePath"
```

> codePath=/data/app/com.src.test
>
> versionName=1.0101